# Accounting and statistics in IIB(IBM Integration Bus)

Tags: messagebroker

What is the command in IIB to generate accounting and statistics data for message flows and their respective applications and integration server. And also how to generate the output file for this data and where is this file stored ?

I have searched a lot regarding this and found the command 'mqsichangeflowstats' from IBM knowledge Center. I was able to successfully execute this command. But I don't know where the file is generated. I am not sure whether this is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

'mqsichangeflowstats' is right. The data will publish to the topic($SYS/Broker/integrationNodeName/StatisticsAccounting/recordType/integrationServerName/messageFlowLabel), and you can subscribe this topic.

FYI
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bc28540_.htm